# How to prevent the child anchor elements of a jQuery UI sortable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, href, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way to deactivate the child anchor `<a href="..." />` elements of a sortable element? For example, you have a table whose table cells may contain links. The table's sortable feature can be turned on and off such that the links can be clicked on whenever sortable is turned off, but cannot when it is turned on. Is this possible?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frqqho75/

Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#sortable").sortable({ disabled: true });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="$('#sortable').sortable('enable');">Activate</button><button onclick="$('#sortable').sortable('disable');">Deactivate</button>
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1 <a href="test">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2 <a href="test">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3 <a href="test">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/frqqho75/